# Disable Root view interaction and Enable subview interaction at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing an app.I have used a view and added a subview to that.My question is when click on a button in root view I added a sub view(tableview). And when i select any  row in table view.then removing the view from super view.when I added the subview to root view..I want to disable root view interaction without effecting the subviews interaction. Is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a transparent or semi-transparent overlay view (Alpha = 0 to 0.5 up to you) which has frame = rootView.frame on top of root view, then put your table view into this overlay view, no touch event can be passed through, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `userInteractionEnabled` affects all subviews of the view it's set to, so no, not in the way you're thinking.  If you wish to disable touch events for a view, subclass it and override `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to forward it's touches to the other view.